# Scroll the SSRollingButtonScrollView to specfic position at launch time

Tags: ios

I have implemented the  [`SSRollingButtonScrollView`](https://github.com/ninefifteen/SSRollingButtonScrollView) . I am using the month Names in array to use with this. Every time I open the application it shows number `MAR` in middle.

There is method

```
- (void)configureCenterButton:(UIButton *)centerButton
```

How do I explicitly pass say button with title text 16 or any other button, so that it can get in the middle at the app launch time?

**Code From Comments**

```
NSArray *digits = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"JAN",@"FEB",@"MAR",@"APR",@"MAY", @"JUN", @"JUL",@"AUG",@"SEPT",@"OCT",@"NOV",@"DEC" ,nil];     
self.HeaderScrollView.AddLabel=YES;
self.HeaderScrollView.fixedButtonWidth = 50.0f;
self.HeaderScrollView.fixedButtonHeight= 45.0f;     
self.HeaderScrollView.spacingBetweenButtons = 0.0f;     
self.HeaderScrollView.notCenterButtonTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];     
self.HeaderScrollView.notCenterButtonBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


self.HeaderScrollView.centerButtonBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];     
[self.HeaderScrollView createButtonArrayWithButtonTitles:digits andLayoutStyle:SShorizontalLayout ];     
[self.HeaderScrollView scrollToButtonIndex:5 animated:YES];     
self.HeaderScrollView.ssRollingButtonScrollViewDelegate = self;     
self.InnerScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(327, self.InnerScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: change your array index at 4th position and try. and ssrollingbuttonscrollview not provide specific position at launch time.

Answer (score 1):

Add following method, you need to pass index of the button which you want to bring to center

Add it in Header file SSRollingButtonScrollView.m as

```
- (void)scrollToButtonIndex:(NSUInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated{
    if(buttonIndex < _rollingScrollViewButtons.count){
        UIButton *aButton = [_rollingScrollViewButtons objectAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        [self moveButtonToViewCenter:aButton animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Declare it in Header file `SSRollingButtonScrollView.h` as

```
- (void)scrollToButtonIndex:(NSUInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

and call it as

```
[self.phoneticSelector01 scrollToButtonIndex:3 animated:YES];
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Whats the issue @user3518271, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have added code to question, please remove comments if possible.